Adding nlohmann_json library to my project, is it necessary to add the entire repo?
I am a newb in cmake and building external libraries.
I am trying to add nlohmann_json library to my project but I don't want to include the entire repository in my project files, I saw in the readme file that I only need the json.hpp file to use in my project; however this file includes multiple other files from the repo.
How do I add this single file and use it instead of adding the entire library and how do I integrate this change into my CMakeLists.txt
set(nlohmann_json_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib/json)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(nlohmann_json 3.2.0 REQUIRED)

# Some Other Configurations

target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)

This was how I integrated the library when I cloned the entire repo

You could use a package manager like vcpkg. Would this be an option? If yes, I can write a more complete answer.

Best way is to use some package manager: vcpkg conan cpm

"I saw in the readme file that I only need the json.hpp file to use in my project" -- Which part of the readme are you looking at? I see "Our whole code consists of a single header file json.hpp." in the readme, but following that link shows a file that does not include multiple other files from the repo.

You should grab the amalgamated file from the single_include directory or the latest release.

You can use the single include header file.. Now there are two ways to get this header file. One way would be directly downloading the file from the location and using it in your project. Another way would be to clone the entire repo and copy the json.hpp header file. Your cmake should look something like below.
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    project(tmp)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} tmp.cpp json.hpp)

